# Cannot take second argument with select max() is used

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Suppose I have table like this attached one.

[![Please refer attached table]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8V11.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8V11.png)

Query1: works fine:

```
select 
    max(SalesAmt)
from
    (select sum(SP * QTY_SOLD) as SalesAmt, Country 
     from SALES 
     group by COUNTRY
     order by SalesAmt desc)
```

Query2: throws this error

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
> 00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

```
select max(SalesAmt), Country 
from
    (select sum(SP * QTY_SOLD) as SalesAmt, Country 
     from SALES 
     group by COUNTRY
     order by SalesAmt desc)
```

The second query should return two columns in the output as both the columns are present in the inner subquery.

Comment: What is expected result, based on sample data you posted?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` clause is superflous. Subquery results are considered unordered data sets. Some DBMS even raise an error, when you out an `ORDER BY` into a subquery. The first query is valid, because it just takes the maximum amount from the subquery (one row, one value). The second query is invalid, because you ask the DBMS to show the maximum amount and *the* country. Which country? You forgot to tell the DBMS which country to pick from the subquery results.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it without subquery and double aggregations grouped by same column. Calculate Sum() - Group by Country - Order by Sum() descending - and fetch just the winnner:

```sql
WITH      --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    sales (ITEM_ID, CP, SP, QTY_SOLD, COUNTRY, CONTINENT, SALES_DATE) AS
        ( Select 3, 1000, 1200, 5, 'INDIA', 'ASIA', DATE '2022-01-14' From Dual Union All
          Select 5, 1200, 1200, 8, 'INDIA', 'ASIA', DATE '2022-01-14' From Dual Union All
          Select 7, 1800, 1900, 10, 'INDIA', 'ASIA', DATE '2022-03-15' From Dual Union All
          Select 8, 4000, 4900, 10, 'INDIA', 'ASIA', DATE '2022-03-17' From Dual Union All
          Select 18, 14000, 14900, 110, 'INDIA', 'ASIA', DATE '2022-04-17' From Dual Union All
          Select 11, 14000, 14900, 120, 'INDIA', 'ASIA', DATE '2023-04-17' From Dual Union All  
          Select 8, 4000, 4800, 10, 'PK', 'ASIA', DATE '2022-04-17' From Dual Union All
          Select 18, 14000, 14800, 110, 'PK', 'ASIA', DATE '2022-04-22' From Dual Union All
          Select 11, 14000, 14100, 120, 'PK', 'ASIA', DATE '2023-04-01' From Dual Union All
          Select 8, 4000, 4800, 10, 'NewZ', 'AUS', DATE '2022-03-21' From Dual Union All
          Select 18, 14000, 14800, 110, 'NewZ', 'AUS', DATE '2022-04-22' From Dual Union All
          Select 11, 14000, 14100, 120, 'NewZ', 'AUS', DATE '2023-10-01' From Dual
        )
```

```sql
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select COUNTRY,  Sum(SP * QTY_SOLD) "MAX_SALES_AMOUNT"
From sales
Group By Country
Order By Sum(SP * QTY_SOLD) Desc
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

...  or (even better) FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES for there could be multiple countries with same result having Max sales result

```sql
/*  R e s u l t
COUNTRY MAX_SALES_AMOUNT
------- ----------------
INDIA            3510600    */
```

Or without FETCH FIRST  ordered descending...

```sql
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select COUNTRY,  Sum(SP * QTY_SOLD) "SALES_AMOUNT"
From sales
Group By Country
Order By Sum(SP * QTY_SOLD) Desc
/*    R e s u l t :
COUNTRY SALES_AMOUNT
------- ------------
INDIA        3510600
NewZ         3368000
PK           3368000    */
```

NOTE: I put PK instead of Pk and pk thinking it was a typo. Anyway you will get what you asked for with your data ...
Next time, please, provide sample data as text (not a picture) so we can copy-paste...

Answer (score 0):

you have to group by again with countery in order to get max or any aggregate function below query should work just fine

```
select max(SalesAmt),Country from 
  (select sum(SP*QTY_SOLD)AS SalesAmt,Country
  FROM SALES group by COUNTRY 
  order by SalesAmt desc)
group by Country
```

Comment: Yes but this above query will give us Countrywise sum(sales) values as follwos.But What I am expecting is I want max(sum(sales)) value with country name.3368000 NewZ
3510600 INDIA
3320000 pk
48000 Pk

Comment: Countrywise  max(sum(sales)) will be only one value

Comment: @SagarHate If you get Sum by Country in your subquery then you wil get one row per country and there is just that row. That makes Max of that value with  country senseless. It is the same value if you leave it as is or tried to get Max(), Min(), or Avg(). All the same...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this should be what you need to achieve in simple term, I dont know you want to use CTE or subquery, they will decrease query performance and use extra ram from server, in other side, if you want to achieve something different, please let me know.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(SP * QTY_SOLD) AS maximum_salesAMT, 
    Country 
FROM 
    SALES 
GROUP BY 
    Country
ORDER BY 
    maximum_salesAMT DESC;
```

Comment: The result of this code is "SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function"

Comment: it doesnt make sense, it is working for me but can you clarify what you want to achieve in the end? summarized sales for each country, or something else?

Comment: Check it out --> https://dbfiddle.uk/6c1zTIWD

Comment: Just needed to remove  max, because oracle doesnt support double aggregation, but it will give the same result because for aggregation every country will get only one row which stands for sum of sales, what you asked in question that why second query doesnt work: it is because you need to use group by in any case if you want to use aggregation function (sum, mean, sd, max, min, first, lag, lead, last etc) therefore you can not call directly max function, but if you want to find max of sum values for each country, then you should have one more grouping variable like beside country

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has special [keep](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html) keyword for this purpose

```
select max (salesamt) salesamt,
       max (country) keep (dense_rank last order by salesamt) country
  from (select (sum (sp * qty_sold)) as salesamt, country
          from sales
         group by country)
```

or without subqueries

```
select max (sum (sp * qty_sold)) as salesamt,
       max (country) keep (dense_rank last order by sum (sp * qty_sold)) country
  from sales
 group by country
```